# ruby-git not able to push

Tags: ruby, git

Hi I am writing aruby script to automate some git steps, for which I am using ruby-git : https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git.

I am able to clone, add and commit my changes but facing the issue while pushing the code changes to remote branch (git push origin ) .

Can anyone help me to push my changes via ruby-git

here is the code :

```
def initiate_git_clone
  path = $config['DbDir']
  git_repo_url = $config['GitRepo']
  git_repo_name = $config['GitRepoName']

  Dir.chdir(path)

  puts "\nStarting cloning : #{git_repo_name}"
  g = Git.clone(git_repo_url, git_repo_name, :path => path)
  puts "Clone completed : #{git_repo_name}"

  g.branch('test_branch')
  g.branch('test_branch').checkout

  update_metrics_status ('generating_schema')
end

def commit_and_push
  db_dir = $config['DbDir']
  git_repo_name = $config['GitRepoName']
  working_dir = db_dir + git_repo_name
  g = Git.open(working_dir)
  g.add
  g.commit('test commit')
  g.push(g.remote('origin'))
end
```

Comment: “but facing the issue while pushing the code changes to remote branch”—do you expect us to divine what kind of issues you face?

Comment: Have you set up ssh keys to access the repo? All the operations that succeeded are local. To access a remote you obviously need to provide credentials.

Comment: It has the ssh key and credentials, that is why its able to clone the repository from remote, The issue is script executed successfully     g.push(g.remote('origin')) without any failures but when I checked at github, I did not found the commit and code.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the [`push` function definition](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git/blob/b48231ecd0f1a95e1f37a983a6ebadad7cc3162c/lib/git/base.rb#L320-L325), try simply:

```
g.push('origin')
```

(Assuming you are working on the `master` branch)

Answer (score 0):

You may checkout to branch again, because the second one is another instance, and select the branch on push:

```
def initiate_git_clone
  path = $config['DbDir']
  git_repo_url = $config['GitRepo']
  git_repo_name = $config['GitRepoName']

  Dir.chdir(path)

  puts "\nStarting cloning : #{git_repo_name}"
  g = Git.clone(git_repo_url, git_repo_name, :path => path)
  puts "Clone completed : #{git_repo_name}"

  g.branch('test_branch')
  g.branch('test_branch').checkout

  update_metrics_status ('generating_schema')
end

def commit_and_push
  db_dir = $config['DbDir']
  git_repo_name = $config['GitRepoName']
  working_dir = db_dir + git_repo_name
  g = Git.open(working_dir)
  g.branch('test_branch').checkout
  g.add
  g.commit('test commit')
  g.push(remote = 'origin', branch = 'test_branch')
end
```